# Java Compare two ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, compare, equals

I have two ArryList.
list1 is always fixed (with Integer) [1, 2, 3, 4].
list2 is filled by an input (with Integer).

Now I want to check if they are equal. Something like:

```
    if (???) {
      System.out.println("equal!");
    }
```

Comment: You need to use a loop to check if each element in the first list matches each element in the second list. If you want to do it in a single line like that then create a method that does this and returns a boolean value then you can call it like so `if(yourCheckMethod(list1, list2)){System.out.println("equal!");}`

Comment: Does the order matter?  For example, should [1, 2, 3, 4] match [4, 1, 3, 2]?

Comment: Yes the order matters. [1, 2, 3, 4] match only with [1, 2, 3, 4].